# How to use generated "Key" in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Since from 2 months I am trying to implement google maps.But still am not done with it.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411338/how-to-handle-over-query-limit),[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165133/path-is-not-accurate?noredirect=1#comment46553241_29165133),[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493201/how-to-find-the-total-distance-traveled-based-on-geo-points-stored-in-database) were my previous doubts.

After a long research I got to know that:-

"Google accepts only 10 requests/sec.If it receives more, then it generates a status 'OVER QUERY LIMIT'.Solutions are to buy that API(not sure about it completely) OR Generate a key with Google Maps which will accept 25000 req/day(Suitable for my requirement)".

Now I have a key.The issue is "It's usage".

Code snippet:

1.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIz************************************"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$(function () {
    //The list of points to be connected

<?php
***********
```

This gives an alert:

"The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it"

2.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true?key=AIz************************************"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$(function () {
    //The list of points to be connected

<?php
***********
```

Usage of sensor removes the alert but it still gives the status 'OVER QUERY LIMIT'.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571750/google-map-error-invalidkeyorunauthorizedurlmaperror) I've tried editing the credentials and all but nothing works out.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v4oo3fn/2/)

Kindly help me out in solving this. If possible give any direct steps, instead of so many links and indirect instruction/comments.

Thank you

Comment: When you use the sensor parameter, use an `&` after it, not a `?`.  Have you enabled the key for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 and the URL you are using it on?

Comment: Ok..The format is like "<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=AIz************************************">"  and Yes I have enabled all available Google API's under 'API's & Auth' and I've given the URL too.Another doubt,we need to use browser key.Isn't it

Comment: I've used this ` <script  
      src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=AIzaS***********************************************s">` It's giving 'Invalid key alert'.And am using browser key,where allowed referers is my website it i.e., "www.asdfg.com/aaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/dddd/" like this and I've enabled Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: @geocodezip I don't understand why your first comment will always be a last comment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should stop using SO...
This answer is for the beginners like me.

1.No need of sensor in Google API V3

2.Use browser key like this - `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIz************************************"></script>`

3.In `Edit allowed references` under  `credentials` give the complete path.
Explained in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999705/4361127)